# Make spawned actors visible during play in Unreal Engine 4?

Tags: unreal-engine4

I'm trying to spawn new actors from by a [constomized console command](http://docs.unrealcv.org/en/latest/plugin/develop.html#add-a-new-command) during game play, (after click play in Editor).

I tried `WorldPtr = GEditor->GetEditorWorldContext().World()`, then `WorldPtr->SpawnActor<ActorClass>`. But the spwaned actor only shown after play stops. I have to begin play again to see these actors.

I also tried get world from game play `GameEngine->GetGameWorld()`, then use that world to spawn actor, the actor can be seen in WorldOutliner Panel, but the actors is gone after play stops.

I wonder how can I spawn actors after begin play, and not disappear after play.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware you cannot. Anything Spawned is destroyed when the session ends.

Why are you wanting them to stay? Have you looked into pausing, then ejecting from your player to inspect?

Comment: I'm not using it for typical game programming, I want some reusable actors after session ends. Never mind, I guess can just work around by copying actor settings for later use.